# Layout Options - Android

Tags: android

Android - I need a layout where I can assemble views in a dynamic manner, Are there any Layouts availible in android where you can specify the locations of buttons and views using coordinates/pixels?

Answer (score 0):

Many layouts in Android can do that.
Android actually has a layout called absolutely layout for specifying views by its postion. But it's not recommended to use.
You can use Linearlayout (or any other Layouts) and use setLayoutParam() method (in Java code) to specify view.

```
LayoutParams layoutParams = new .LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.leftMargin = some_value;//in pixel
layoutParams.rightMargin = some_value;//in pixel
    ....
yourView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

That above code will set your view to a specific pixel you want.